# Exporting variables in sass

Tags: sass

Consider the following example of 3 scss files:

```
//main.scss`
@use 'deep1' as *;
body {
   background-color: $color;
}

// deep1.scss
@use 'deep2' as *;


// deep2.scss
$color: red;
```

If I run this in scss I get an error that the $color variable is undefined. Is there any way to achieve this kind of variable nesting with scss? In other words, if `file1` uses resources from `file2`, how can I automatically tell sass that any file that will use `file1` should also use `file2`?

I am thinking about some exporting function or anything if it is present in `dart-sass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can @forward 'deep2' at the begining of 'deep1' like so:

```
@forward "deep2";
```

[From the documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#loading-members):

> Members (variables, functions, and mixins) loaded with @use are only
> visible in the stylesheet that loads them. Other stylesheets will need
> to write their own @use rules if they also want to access them. This
> helps make it easy to figure out exactly where each member is coming
> from. If you want to load members from many files at once, you can use
> the @forward rule to forward them all from one shared file.

Alternatively you could use @import instead of @use:

```
@import 'deep2';
```

Comment: `@forward` is the solution here. The whole reason of my question was that I am trying to migrate away from `@import` because it will be deprecated soon as per the docs:)

Comment: I should agree... and edited my answer to reflect that ;)